# overflow-hidden in reactstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

In bootstrap 4 docs, there're `overflow-hidden` and `overflow-auto` classes for elements, but in `reactstrap` if I try this:

```
<Col xs={3} className="overflow-hidden">
    <Sidebar/>
</Col>
```

That `col` does not get `overflow: hidden`. How to use `overflow-{}` classes in `reactstrap`?

UPD: It seems that that class doesn't exist:

[image: Overflow search]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of bootstrap classes with reactstrap as follows:

Install following dependencies

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4.2.1
npm install --save reactstrap
```

Add the following line in the component where you like to use Bootstrap 4 classes:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. `<Col xs={3} className="overflow-hidden">` still has no effect with that import

Comment: If you inspect the code you can see that overflow-hidden class with overflow: hidden css is applied to your <div>

Comment: @NikitinRoman Do you have bootstrap installed (npm install --save bootstrap) and if yes what is the version of bootstrap, you can find this in your package.json

Comment: @NikitinRoman just tried it and it is working, you can find the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/43kkrwry6w

Comment: @NikitinRoman  have tried it with    "reactstrap": "7.0.0" and "bootstrap": "4.2.1", versions and its working you can have a look on the following fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/43kkrwry6w

Comment: bootstrap is v4.1.3

Comment: Well, overflow is missing in 4.1.3, as it was added in 4.2.x, so technically the answer would be to update bootstrap to the latest version :)

Comment: try to update the bootstrap version and have a look on following fiddle, that may help you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/43kkrwry6w